# Inject Services into partional razor componet class

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I want to split code in razor components. Html markup and logic.
I am really new C#. 
When I try it like this

TaskManagement.razor.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MintWebApp.Services;
using MintDataService;

namespace WebApp.Pages 
{
    partial class TaskManagement 
    {
        public TaskService _taskService;

        public TaskManagement(TaskService taskService)
        {
            _taskService = taskService;
        }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            MintTaskFromJson task = await _taskService.GetExampleTask();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 
'WebApp.Pages.TaskManagement'.
```

Which is the best way to inject services into the partinal class without inject the service in the razor file

Comment: If anyone finds this from a Google Search and STILL can't get it to work for some -bizarre- reason.

Check your App and _Host file to make sure they are valid.
I fixed this on mine and Visual Studio magically saw the partial class properly.
I had a string issue -- specifically $"" type string but didn't close it on the same line.. and VS freaked out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the `Inject` attribute

```
[Inject]
public TaskService TaskService { get; set; }
```

And don't forget to add dependency injection to your service

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<TaskService, TaskService>();
}
```

You can take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-services-to-an-app) that explains it.

Also found a [tutorial](https://blazor-tutorial.net/dependency-injection) that explains it.

## Edit:

You should also notice that you can also inject it in the `.razor` file

```
@inject TaskService TaskService
```

Comment: Everything you say in your Edit section is false. I know where it came from. So first off, let me tell you this: Don't listen to anybody...check for yourself. You can inject a service in the partial class file (.razor.cs) , and access it directly from the view portion of the component (.razor), and vice versa, you can inject the service in the view portion of the component (.razor),  and access it directly from the partial class file (.razor.cs). Your distinction between "blazor component (.razor)" and "partial class (.razor.cs)"  is wrong. Both parts constitute the component.

Comment: And indeed the compiler creates a single partial class which derives from the ComponentBase class
in which the services are injected as well. Understand this: The Razor view portion of the component 
is merged with the code portion (whether you use a partial class or a code block makes no difference)
into a single class.

Comment: Also, the Inject attribute is not valid on a field. It is valid on a property. It should be : [Inject]
public TaskService _taskService { get; set; }

Comment: @enet You are totally right! The part about the getter and setter was a very big typo because I just copied from the question without testing it

Comment: @enet About the `I know where it came from. So first off, let me tell you this: Don't listen to anybody` you don't know where it came from. The real reason for me to think that is because other things like `inherit` don't work in both cases, you need to use it in the `.razor` file. But don't worry, I'm editing it to make right, thanks for helping me with that part

Comment: @enet about the `Your distinction between "blazor component (.razor)" and "partial class (.razor.cs)" is wrong` could you tell me what would be the correct distinction? The wrong part is that I say `blazor component` as everything is a blazor component? What is wrong and why?

Comment: @enet and also, if you see mistakes like that, you can always edit the answer to improve it

Comment: have you seen  my comments the have been removed. I wonder why ?

Comment: @enet my comment also got removed

Comment: I see all your comments in place, but my response to you four comments above have been removed. The question is whether you've read them... If you are interested I can post them again.